# How to configure Xcode external build system to build and clean using standard short-cuts?

Tags: xcode

[Xcode 10.1, MacOS 10.14.1]

I have a project that uses `bmake` (could be any `make` though) and the Makefile provides a number of targets.  I would like to use Xcode to build `host` and clean the build folder, but I'm having trouble working out how configure Xcode to allow me to this.

From the command line, I would build using `bmake host` and clean using `bmake clean`.  The reason I'm using Xcode for this is because I like to use an IDE for debugging.

In `Project -> Info (External Build Tool Configuration)`, I have:

```
Build Tool  :  /usr/local/bin/bmake
Arguments   :  host
Directory   :  None     <- I'm using the current path
```

With these settings, `Product -> Build` builds my target, but `Product -> Clean Build Folder` does nothing even though Xcode reports that the clean succeeded.

In order to actually do a clean, I either need to define another target with the `Arguments` field set to `clean` and then switch between targets when building/cleaning, or, use a single target and change the argument field depending on whether I'm building or cleaning.  (A really clumsy way of going about it.)

If I leave `Arguments` with it's default value `$(ACTION)` all targets get built (except clean), and cleaning does nothing useful.

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652316/setup-xcode-for-using-external-compiler but that question does not address this problem.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: For those voting to close this question to SO, I don't see this as being a coding question.  I'm reading it as a question for how to do something in the Xcode application and, if correct, that should be on-topic for this site.

Comment: Lelt's see whether this gets answered in the next day or two. If not, please flag for mod attention so we can migrate the question to SO.

Answer (score 1):

The approach we are using:

1. Run external build system (i.e. Make or CMake) via custom script from "External Build System" target or just as a "Run script" build phase.
2. At some point of custom script execution save a text file (say `CMakeStatus.txt`) to `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`, which will be used as a **flag** indicating that Xcode did clean.
3. In your custom script check that `CMakeStatus.txt` is present or not. If not, then rebuild your external build system.

Here is example of using Cmake and rebuilding it if Xcode did a clean.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

require 'fileutils'

# system("printenv | sort")

AppProjectName = ENV['PROJECT_NAME']
AppBuildRootDir = ENV['AWL_CMAKE_BUILDS']
AppBuildDirPath = ENV['BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR']
AppPlatform = ENV['PLATFORM_NAME']
AppBuildConfig = ENV['CONFIGURATION']
AppTargetDeviceId = ENV['TARGET_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER']
if AppProjectName.nil?
   raise "❌ Variable \"PROJECT_NAME\" is not passed to script."
end
if AppBuildRootDir.nil?
   raise "❌ Variable \"AWL_CMAKE_BUILDS\" is not passed to script."
end
if AppBuildDirPath.nil?
   raise "❌ Variable \"BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR\" is not passed to script."
end
if AppPlatform.nil?
   raise "❌ Variable \"PLATFORM_NAME\" is not passed to script."
end
if AppBuildConfig.nil?
   raise "❌ Variable \"CONFIGURATION\" is not passed to script."
end

WhiteListedVars = ["PATH", "HOME"]
ENV.keys.each { |key|
   if !WhiteListedVars.include? key
      ENV[key] = nil
   end
}
AppNewEnvVars = `bash -l -c printenv`.strip.split("\n")
AppNewEnvVars.each { |var|
   components = var.split("=", 2)
   key = components[0]
   value = components[1]
   ENV[key] = value
}

# system("printenv | sort")

AppCmakeBuildDirPath = "#{AppBuildRootDir}/#{AppProjectName}"
AppCmakeCacheFilePath = "#{AppCmakeBuildDirPath}/CMakeCache.txt"
AppCmakeStatusFilePath = "#{AppBuildDirPath}/CMakeStatus.txt"

if !File.exist?(AppCmakeStatusFilePath) && Dir.exist?(AppCmakeBuildDirPath)
   puts "✅ Deleting previous build at \"#{AppCmakeBuildDirPath}\"..."
   FileUtils.rm_rf(AppCmakeBuildDirPath)
end

if !File.exist?(AppCmakeCacheFilePath)
   puts "✅ Generating Cmake for Platform \"#{AppPlatform}\"..."
   cmd = "cmake -G Xcode -B \"#{AppCmakeBuildDirPath}\" -DCMAKE_Swift_COMPILER_FORCED=true -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=#{AppBuildConfig} "
   if AppPlatform == "macosx"
      cmd += "-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13"
   elsif
      cmd += "-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS"
   end
   puts cmd
   system cmd
   File.write(AppCmakeStatusFilePath, 'This file used just as a status flag to clean Cmake.')
end

puts "✅ Building Cmake for Platform \"#{AppPlatform}\" ..."

cmd = "set -euf -o pipefail && cd \"#{AppCmakeBuildDirPath}\" && cmake --build \"#{AppCmakeBuildDirPath}\" -- -quiet CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=\"#{AppBuildDirPath}\" "
if AppPlatform == "macosx"
   cmd += "-destination 'platform=OS X,arch=x86_64'"
elsif AppPlatform == "iphonesimulator"
   if AppTargetDeviceId.nil?
      raise "❌ Variable \"TARGET_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER\" is not passed to script."
   end
   cmd += "-sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=#{AppTargetDeviceId}'"
else
   if AppTargetDeviceId.nil?
      cmd += "-sdk iphoneos -destination generic/platform=iOS"
   else
      cmd += "-sdk iphoneos -destination 'platform=iOS,id=#{AppTargetDeviceId}'"
   end
end

# cmd += " | xcpretty"
puts cmd
system(cmd) or exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Makefile-based project with a `clean` target and I was able to get that target to run in Xcode 10.3 with the standard <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut by choosing "Legacy Build System" from *File* → *Project Settings…*

[image: "Build System" selection under File -> Project Settings in Xcode 10.3]

Now choose *Product* → *Clean*, or use the hotkey. Go to the Report navigator (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>).

Right click the somewhere in the middle of the most recent "Clean" results report and choose "Expand All Transcripts" in order to see the verbose output from the invocation of `make`, including all environment variables set by Xcode:

[image: Xcode Report navigator for 'Clean' report]

By scrolling all the way down to the bottom of this expanded output, you'll be able to see your `make clean` target running.

Hope this helps!